# Get MailItem after Items.ItemAdd event

Tags: c++, events, outlook, mailitem

I'm trying to get the size and the conversation index of an email after it's meved to the sent mail folder.

```
STDMETHODIMP CItemsEventListener::HandleItemAdd(DISPPARAMS* pDispParams, CString p_csDate, CString p_csTime)
{
    HRESULT l_hResult;
    CMailItem l_mailItem = NULL ;
    IDispatch * m_disp = pDispParams->rgvarg[1].pdispVal;
    l_hResult = m_disp->QueryInterface(IID_MailItemItems, (void**)&l_mailItem);
    //Do stuff
}
```

The QueryInterface method generates an exception. (access violation). 
Ps: Im using the very same CMailItem class with application events and it works well.
What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, how is that method invoked?

Secondly, you are accessing the second parameter (rgvarg[**1**].pdispVal). You need to use the first parameter (rgvarg[**0**].pdispVal).

Comment: Changing the parameter number solved he issue, thanks.

Comment: re @dmitry, I've noticed that with Outlook 2010, the itemadd event is not triggered (on the default sentmails box). I think it's beause Outlook 2010 separates the outboxes according to the accounts which they belong to.

My new question is, how to capture ItemAdd event (after an email is sent, i mean when it's beeing added to the sentmails box) regardless  which account it belongs to?

Comment: Sure, if an item goes to the Sent Items folder in a different store, you need to hook up events on that particular store. Do you see the events in OutlookSpy if you go to that Sent Items folder, click Folder button,. select Items, click Browse, go to the Events tab?